# Is it possible to run FreeRDP without a display for running scripts?

Tags: ssh, windows, freerdp, rdesktop, xfreerdp

I am working in a very strict enviroment where I only have access to a remote computer via RDP and it is impossible for me to enable SSH or SFTP etc on the other computer. I CAN connect to the computer through FreeRDP however as far as I know this is only useful in order to enable you just launch a display.

Basically my question is there an option that I can feed into FreeRDP so that I can execute a single command on the remote desktop without a need for a display.

**Is there a way to Use/Hack FreeRDP to use it LIKE SSH**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use freerdp via xvfb (fake xserver display). 
It simulates an X display and runs app without screen drawings:

```
xvfb-run xterm -e /bin/bash -c "ping -c4 localhost > /tmp/out.txt"
```

Also scripting freerdp:

https://warroom.rsmus.com/scripting-rdp/